# JavaScript - Video Tag

Tags: jquery, html, video

I have a video-tag in html-
I will stop my video with javascript after 20 and after 40 seconds and then show a Lightbox. And when the Lightbox closed, should the video play again.

i tried it so

```
this.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function(){
    if (this.video.currentTime >= 6) {
        this.showAnlageType();
    }
});
```

But its false, can you help me please?

Comment: I hate it when things are **`flase`**....

Comment: `this` is not the context that you think it is.

Answer (score 2):

the `this` reference within the function callback is a different context than the `this` used to bind the event listener. Store a reference to `this` and use the stored reference:

```
var self;
self = this;
this.video.addEventListener("timeupdate", function() {
    if (self.video.currentTime >= 6) {
        self.showAnlageType();
    }
});
```

Comment: Inside the event, `this` is the element, so `this.currentTime` will work too.